# How to create in SQLAlchemy model row with random string when Postgresql is under?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How to create in SQLAlchemy model row with random string when Postgresql is under?

I need to convert from MySQL where I can do like this.

```
Column(uuid_generator.GUID(), default=uuid.uuid4, nullable=False, unique=True)

import uuid

class GUID(types.TypeDecorator):
    """Platform-independent GUID type, Uses Postgresql's UUID type, otherwise uses CHAR(32), storing as stringified hex values."""
    impl = CHAR

    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        if dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return dialect.type_descriptor(UUID())
        else:
            return dialect.type_descriptor(CHAR(32))

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        elif dialect.name == 'postgresql':
            return str(value)
        else:
            if not isinstance(value, uuid.UUID):
                return "%.32x" % uuid.UUID(value)
            else:
                # hexstring
                return "%.32x" % value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is None:
            return value
        else:
            return uuid.UUID(value)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Is under"? Do you mean when you are using PostgreSQL as your database backend?

Comment: You can do the same for Postgresql, as `uuid.uuid4` is actually a python function, and not RDBMS specific.

Comment: @van I got error ProgrammingError type binary does not exist, BINARY(16) NOT NULL, but it works for mysql

Comment: Have you read about and tried to use native Postgresql [UUID](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID) type?